# Vuejs button color based on axios response

Tags: laravel, axios, vuejs3

I have a Laravel / Vuejs 3 / Inertia app.

I have a db table with a list of images associated with articles.
Table structure:

```
id | created_at | updated_at | filename | type | sequenza_visualizzazione | article_codice_base | published | validato
```

In the filename field I store the filename of the image without path; in the type I store a string needed to get the right path.

On a Vue js page, I have a table with a row for each image present in the table related to a specific article. When I load the page I need to make the button color red if the image saved in the db is not present on disk.

This is a piece of code of the table; as you can see I call isFilePresent and I want to make background white or red-5 based on the response.

```js
<script setup>
import { useQuasar } from 'quasar'
import axios from 'axios'

const isFilePresent = (tipo, filename) => {
  axios
    .post('/api/checkIfImageExist', { tipo: tipo, filename: filename })
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response.data)
      return response.data
    })
}
</script>
```

```html
<template>
  <template #body-cell-actions="props">
    <q-td :props="props">
      <q-btn
        icon="image"
        :color="
          isFilePresent('galleries', props.row.filename) == 'true'
            ? 'white'
            : 'red-5'
        "
        text-color="black"
        @click="onShowGalleryFilename(props.row.filename)"
        ><q-tooltip>Visualizza anteprima</q-tooltip></q-btn
      >
    </q-td>
  </template>
</template>
```

Checking on chrome dev tools the response of the 5 records, I have 3 responses with false and two calls that give me true as response. Anyway all the buttons have red background.

I thought that the behaviour can be related with the asynchronous behaviour of the axios command; anyway I was not able to fix it.

Any help?

Comment: The database information is irrelevant.  Template code runs synchronously.  `isFilePresent` is going to return a false result every time because it can't wait for the axios result to return.  You need to modify some reactive data instead.  This is a QTable? The table has some `items` associated with it, which you should make reactive if it's not already.  Modify `items` directly with the async result, maybe add some new `item.color` property and use that with your `q-btn`. You don't need to bind a method to the `:color` prop then.

Answer (score 0):

Axios returns a promise you can not use the return value of axios like that.

you can do something like this

```
 const isFilePresent = async (tipo, filename) => {
  const response = await axios.post('/api/checkIfImageExist', { tipo: tipo, filename: filename })    
  return response.data
}
```

But a better way is to check the file presentation on the server, on the first request that you fetch the table's data not like the approach you using now